# How to find colored images only, excluding hollow images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, automation, ui-automation

I need to capture all applications icons , I found some code to do so, but 
it captures also lock an favorites hubs,I need to exclude them.
my code is:

```
def identify_objects_and_crop(image):
    image = cv2.imread(str(image))
    edged = cv2.Canny(image, 10, 250)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
    closed = cv2.morphologyEx(edged, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    # finding_contours
    cnts, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), 
    cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)                                              

   idx = 1
   for c in contours:
       x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
       if w > 50 and h > 50:
           new_img = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
           cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', new_img)
           idx += 1
identify_objects_and_crop("some img path")
```

[image: screenshot]

Any idea?

Comment: What is a "hollow image"?

Comment: Does OpenCV the right tool for it? Why just to load the images in a python regular program and check if the file is actually a image?

Comment: maybe you can test some points inside the image, and check if the color is black or white.... if all of them are black and white is hollow... for that you can try to turn every white pixel black, and then for the rectangle of each image do, [countNonZero](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) and if it gives at least 20% of the area it is not hollow.... (I said 20% since some logos may have white)... this is just a suggestion